# Is SQL Server is installed on local machine

Tags: sql-server, wix, installed-applications

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to detect SQL Server Express in WiX installer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/684950/how-to-detect-sql-server-express-in-wix-installer)

I am planning to install SQL Server in silent mode via installer of my application.
What is the best way to detect that SQL Server Express 2008 is installed on machine?

Some of my assumptions:

1. Searching an entry in registry. But which KEY to check..? And this entry must be erased on uninstalling Server.
2. Try to connect to Server and analyse the result.
3. Custom action that will detect an active SQL Server service..

Comment: You could also find some additional info here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/141154/how-can-i-determine-installed-sql-server-instances-and-their-versions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The blog entry at the following link shows how to use WMI to see if SQL Express is installed. You could use the information in this article to write a helper. It seems to be good for SQL 2005 or later. The article does not recommend checking the registry.
[SQL Server Express WebLog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlexpress/archive/2006/07/29/faq-detecting-sql-server-2005-using-wmi.aspx)