# How to check if SQL Server is installed in wix 3.5

Tags: wix, wix3.5

What am I doing wrong here. I got this code from [StackOverFlow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/684950/how-to-detect-sql-server-express-in-wix-installer) but none of them works.

```
   <Property Id="SQLSERVER_INSTANCE">
      <RegistrySearch Id="SQLServerRegSearch" Root="HKLM" Key="SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server" Type="raw" Name="InstalledInstances"/>
    </Property>
    <Feature Id="DatabaseFeature" Title="Database" Level="1" Display="expand">
      <Condition Level="0">
        <![CDATA[SQLSERVER_INSTANCE = ""]]>
      </Condition>
      <ComponentRef Id='SqlComponent' />
      <ComponentRef Id='cmpMDF' />
      <ComponentRef Id='cmpLDF' />
    </Feature>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This works:

```
<Property Id="ISSQLSERVERSERVICEINSTALLED" >
  <RegistrySearch Id="IsSqlServerServiceInstalled" Root="HKLM" Key="SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\MSSQLSERVER" Name="Description" Type="raw"/>
</Property>
```

Comment: This doeinstasn't work for me. I have SQL Server installed and don't have this key. I have keys for individual instance names and SqlBrowser

Answer (score 0):

There is a difference in the SQL Server Registry Keys between 32-bit and 64-bit versions of Windows.

This is most likely the reason your WiX code is not working.

See this Blog for some comprehensive code snippets : http://robs-got-a-blog.blogspot.com/2011/08/detecting-sql-server-from-wix-installer.html